# Read .tiff to byte array in memory and then conver to image

Tags: c#, image, memorystream

I have been handed a project that involves reading records from an Access database table and placing this information into a large PDF booklet.

One of the columns in the Access table is a MEMO column that contains .tiff image information. I gathered this from the fact that the file information when written to a text file begins with "II*", which I have read is a .tiff header stating that the file is in Intel byte order.

So, with that being said, I need to convert this MEMO field into an image and write that image to the PDF, which I'd like to accomplish in memory if possible.

The code I have so far for the actual conversion is this:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace ElectionsPollBooks
{
    class ImageConversion
    {
        public Image ConvertMemo(string s_convert)
        {

            byte[] ba_incTiff = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s_convert);//string of information from the Memo field in the Access Database
            using (MemoryStream ms_incTiffImage = new MemoryStream(ba_incTiff))//takes our just converted byte array and reads it to memory as the input tiff
            {
                return Image.FromStream(ms_incTiffImage);//take said tiff stream that we just made, and return it as an image.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now I am getting the `"Parameter is not valid"` error on the `return Image.FromStream(ms_incTiffImage);` method, which I understand means the byte array isn't in any form of data that the `Image.FromStream()` method understands.

This leads me to wonder if maybe my issue is reading the string in using the Unicode encoding in this line: `byte[] ba_incTiff = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s_convert);`

But this all new territory for me and I am not sure if my thought process is right with this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you all for your time.

**UPDATE:**
When I output the MEMO field to a text file with             `File.WriteAllText(@"Irrevelvant\Path\Foo\test.txt", s_convert);`

I end up with this as a snippet from the output:

> II* ê  €?àP8$ „BaP¸d6ˆDbQ8¤V-ŒFcQ¸äv=HdR9$–M'”JeR¹d¶]/˜LfS9¤Öm7œNgS¹äö}?

Some additional information:

`ba_incTiff` ends up with a count of 14176 bytes, the first 5 are 73,0,73,0,42 (I'm not sure if it is relevant, but I am grabbing at straws right now).

**UPDATE**

I was able to discover if there was any special encoding placed on the information being stored in the MEMO filed to find out there was none.

By changing `byte[] ba_incTiff = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(s_convert)` to `byte[] ba_incTiff = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(s_convert);`, I was able to get past the problem.

Now, however, I am receiving a `A generic error occurred in GDI+.` error...

Comment: So the image is stored as a string in Access? I think you'll need to determine exactly how that string was generated. `Encoding.X.GetBytes(s)` will get the bytes representing a string, rather than a real conversion from a string representation of an original byte array. Usually a byte array stored as a string will be base64 or hex - is the data one of these two formats?

Comment: @JoeEnos thanks for the information. I'll have to go see exactly how the information is being imported to the database in the first place. I was literally just handed a test database and said, "Make it work...". But now I know I'll have to go see what the end users are actually doing to store this.

Comment: If you can provide a small sample of the text here of one of the images, it might be clear what type it is...

Comment: First thing i would try is to copy the data out of access into a txt file change extension to a tiff then see if it opens then you can also tweak the encoding and see if that helps

Comment: @MikeT You can't copy/paste binary data through text editors.

Comment: @JoeEnos I added a snippet of the outputted text file and also a little on the byte array was returning as well.

Comment: I'd bet the data is garbage - that it was inserted incorrectly in the first place. Has anyone confirmed that anybody ever successfully read images from that table? If so, does anyone have source code of the app that did? It looks like somebody took a byte array of an image, did `Encoding.UTF8.GetString` (or similar) on that image, then dumped that string in the DB. If that happened, then the data is not retrievable, since the string doesn't accurately reflect the bytes.

Comment: The proper way to store a byte array as a string would be something that uses printable characters only (specifically printable ASCII characters) that can be converted back and forth with no ambiguity. That's where Base64, Hex, ASCII-85, basE91, etc., come in. Base64 would probably be the most common, because it is consistent (3 bytes = 4 characters, not including the padding), and also easy to read. Hex is easy to read but bigger, and ASCII85 and basE91 are smaller but less common, less consistent, and harder to read.

Comment: @JoeEnos To add a little more context from what I have gathered from this project, the old system they used is some archaic FoxPro program to extract the information from this table and add it to a PDF that way (outisde my scope of knowledge, or any other programmer here). Now, with that being said, I still need to go meet with the end user who IMPORTS this info. I also learned from digging around that FoxPro adds some garbage data to these formats when importing and exporting information...which could be my issue of the program used to insert the data in the first place is a FoxPro app.

Comment: @JoeEnos I am by no means a computer expert in lower-level computing either, but I really was sure that there had to some kind of encoding error on this or something added just by how the memo field was being written in a .txt file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112322/discussion-between-gary-taylor717-and-joe-enos).